# UWP wampsharp warnings

Tags: c#, uwp

I would like to ask if it is possible to use the wampsharp library in the UWP project. For me, after adding the nuget wampsharp and wamsharp.default package everything works but I have warnings.

```
warning MSB3277: Found conflicts between different versions of "System.Linq.Queryable" that could not be resolved.  These reference conflicts are listed in the build log when log verbosity is set to detailed.
warning MSB3277: Found conflicts between different versions of "System.ComponentModel.EventBasedAsync" that could not be resolved.  These reference conflicts are listed in the build log when log verbosity is set to detailed.
warning MSB3277: Found conflicts between different versions of "System.Diagnostics.Tools" that could not be resolved.  These reference conflicts are listed in the build log when log verbosity is set to detailed.
warning MSB3277: Found conflicts between different versions of "System.Diagnostics.Debug" that could not be resolved.  These reference conflicts are listed in the build log when log verbosity is set to detailed.
warning MSB3277: Found conflicts between different versions of "System.Linq.Parallel" that could not be resolved.  These reference conflicts are listed in the build log when log verbosity is set to detailed.
warning MSB3277: Found conflicts between different versions of "System.Threading.Tasks" that could not be resolved.  These reference conflicts are listed in the build log when log verbosity is set to detailed.
warning MSB3277: Found conflicts between different versions of "System.Threading" that could not be resolved.  These reference conflicts are listed in the build log when log verbosity is set to detailed.
warning MSB3277: Found conflicts between different versions of "System.ComponentModel" that could not be resolved.  These reference conflicts are listed in the build log when log verbosity is set to detailed.
```

I have already tried all the solutions I could find. These warnings appear even in an empty project.
Is it possible to use somehow wampsharp in UWP?

Comment: try this url: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/f28bf5ac-c7f0-43fc-a70f-8b0170fc56d4/how-to-fix-warning-msb3277-found-conflicts-between-different-versions-of-the-same-dependent?forum=lightswitch

Comment: in the project I have no option to remove unused references ... do I need any plugin ??

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce what you've posted above. Any chance you can help with some more description? Here's what I tried: new UWP app, set the min OS version to 16299+ (love that RS3), Add v19.8.1 of wampsharp, build both in DEBUG and RELEASE config for x86. No errors.

Comment: I have the OS version set to 10586 ... I changed to a higher one in the test empty project and there are no warnings. Thank you for the hint :)